How to solve the following differential equation of order 1
How to solve the following differential equation of order 1
I tried variable separation and exact
$y'=\sqrt{4x+2y-1}$

You should add your attempt.

Hint: substitute $u = 4 x + 2 y - 1$.

This differential equation is of the form
$y' = f(ax + by)$.
These equations can be solved via the change of variables
$z = ax + by$.
In our case, that would mean (a = 4, b = 2)
$z = 4x + 2y$
$\implies z' = 4 + 2y'$
Plugging back into the equation gives:
$\frac{z'}{2} - 2 = \sqrt{(z - 1)}$
$z' = 4 + 2\sqrt{z - 1}$
The equation is now separable. Just remember to solve for $y$ once you've solved for $z$!

It miss a coefficient 2 in the last equation.

Thanks, I'll edit it!
